# Multithreaded Client-Server socket programming in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I'm having an issue with a messaging app I'm working on and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm stuck on getting the client and server to communicate properly.

My client multicasts a message to 5 processes, which make their alterations on the server side and send them back to the client. This all works fine, however when I try to multicast a second time, the server is getting stuck reading and eventually gives me the error: W/System.err (with no other information) at the line I point out in the code.

Client code:

```
private class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... msgs) {

        try{

            String msg = msgs[0];
            int ID = Integer.parseInt(msgs[1]);
            ObjectOutputStream out;
            clock++;
            Message m1 = new Message(clock, msg, ID);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

                String remotePort = REMOTE_PORT[i];
                Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                        Integer.parseInt(remotePort));

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(m1);
                out.flush();

                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Message m2 = (Message)in.readObject();

                proposed_seq_from_q = m2.seq_number;
                all_proposed.add(proposed_seq_from_q);

                socket.close();
            }

            agreed_deliver = Collections.max(all_proposed);

            m1.set_seq_number(agreed_deliver);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

                String remotePort = REMOTE_PORT[i];
                Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                        Integer.parseInt(remotePort));

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(m1);
                out.flush();
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask: ClassNotFoundException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask: UnknownHostException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask: IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
    private class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<ServerSocket, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ServerSocket... sockets) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = sockets[0];
        boolean listening = true;

        try{
            while(listening) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                Message m = (Message)in.readObject();

                new_proposed = Math.max(new_proposed + 1, clock);
                m.set_seq_number(new_proposed);

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(m);

                holdback_queue.add(m);

// ******************************************************
//       THIS IS WHERE IT IS CRASHING
// ******************************************************
                m = (Message)in.readObject();

                publishProgress(m.get_message());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I'm unable to get the server to read the second message. Everything is working up and being passed through with no issues up until that exact point. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?